# How can I get a distinct result of more than one field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have the following table:

```
Field1      Field2      Field3
AAA         BBB         CCC
BBB
AAA         DDD     
CCC         BBB         EEE
BBB                     FFF
```

How can I get the following result with one query?

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

In words, I want to get a list of all different entries of these 3 fields, but each entry only one time.
With only one field I would have used the distinct, but this is not possible here, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select field1 as field from your_table
union
select field2 from your_table
union
select field3 from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from  (
select Field1 from `table`
union
select Field2 as Field1 from `table`
union
select Field3 as Field1 from `table`)
group by Field1
```